# Create a csv thanks to web scraping multiple page with python or pyspark

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, pyspark

I'm trying for the first time to webscrape a website and i would like to create a csv file  from webscraping of a japanese animation website with title, gender, studio and duration of anime.

I only managed to collect the data of the titles of the first page with that code :

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
res = requests.get("http://www.animeka.com/animes/series/~_1.html")
soup = BeautifulSoup(res.content, "html.parser")
anime_containers = soup.find_all('table', class_ = 'animesindex')
names = []

for container in anime_containers:

    if container.find_all('td', class_ = 'animestxt') is not None:
        name = container.a.text
        names.append(name)
        
import pandas as pd

test_df = pd.DataFrame({'anime': names})
print(test_df)
```

and getting something like that :

```
anime
0   "Eikou Naki Tensai-tachi" kara no Monogatari
1                                 "Eiyuu" Kaitai
2                              "Parade" de Satie
3                                       ?l DLIVE
4                   'n Gewone blou Maandagoggend
5                                    +Tic Neesan
6                          .hack// Terminal Disc
7                           .hack//G.U. Returner
8                            .hack//G.U. Trilogy
```

**I don't know how to gather gender, studio and duration and how to scrape all other page without reiterate same code**

this is the source code of the page view-source:[http://www.animeka.com/animes/series/~_1.html](http://www.animeka.com/animes/series/%7E_1.html)

Comment: and ? what is your problem ?

Comment: I don't know how to gather gender, studio and duration and how to scrape all other page without reiterate same code i got data only from page one there's 466 page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To iterate over all the pages, you simply need to use a `for` loop and change the page number in the url like this:

```
for page_no in range(1, 467):
    url = 'http://www.animeka.com/animes/~_{}.html'.format(page_no)
```

Now, to get the information you want, you can use this:

```
titles, studios, genres, durations = [], [], [], []

for page_no in range(1, 467):
    url = 'http://www.animeka.com/animes/~_{}.html'.format(page_no)
    r = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml')

    for table in soup.find_all('table', class_='animesindex'):
        td = table.find_all('td', class_='animestxt')
        titles.append(td[1].text.split(':')[1])
        studios.append(td[3].text.split(':')[1])
        genres.append(td[4].text.split(':')[1])
        durations.append(td[6].text.split(':')[1])

headers = ['Title', 'Studio', 'Genres', 'Duration']
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(zip(headers, [titles, studios, genres, durations])))
print(df)
```

Partial Output:

```
                                            Title                   Duration                                             Genres                                             Studio
0    "Eikou Naki Tensai-tachi" kara no Monogatari    TV-S 25 mins (en cours)                          [SPORT] [TRANCHE DE VIE]                      [NHK ENTERPRISE] [J.C. STAFF] 
1                                  "Eiyuu" Kaitai                      1 OAV                                         [COMéDIE]                                            [ZEXCS] 
2                               "Parade" de Satie             1 FILM 14 mins         [FANTASTIQUE & MYTHE] [COMéDIE] [MUSICAL]                               [YAMAMURA ANIMATION] 
3                                         elDLIVE               Non spécifié         [ACTION] [COMéDIE] [ESPACE & SCI-FICTION]                                 [PIERROT CO.,LTD.] 
4                    'n Gewone blou Maandagoggend              1 FILM 3 mins                                           [DRAME]                                            [AUCUN]
```

Comment: with that base, I would like to get user id and what's rating did they put for which anime did u have any idea to get that, in the website the rating is in an image i dunno how to exploit it ?

Comment: I think you should ask another question regarding that. It's out of scope for this question.

Answer (score 0):

This little program shows how to scrap one page that can help maybe not the best solution, you can modify this to suit your needs:
(from http://www.animeka.com/animes/series/~_1.html to http://www.animeka.com/animes/series/~_466.html)

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

animation_list = []
url = "http://www.animeka.com/animes/series/~_1.html"
page_source = requests.get(url).content
soup = BeautifulSoup(page_source, "html5lib")
tag_list = soup.find_all("td", {"class" : "animestxt"})
result_list = []

for tag in tag_list:
    if "TITRE ORIGINAL" in tag.text:
        data_string = tag.text.split("\n")
        tmp_dic = {}
        for index in data_string:
            line = index.strip()
            if len(line) == 0:
                continue
            if not line[0].isalpha():
                continue
            if line not in ["", " ", "  "]:
                tmp_dic[line.split(":")[0]] = line.split(":")[1]
        result_list.append(tmp_dic)

for list_index in result_list:
    if len(list_index) != 6:
        continue
    for item in list_index:
        print("{} : {}".format(item, list_index[item]))
    print("==================")
```

Output:

```
TITRE ORIGINAL  :  "Eikou Naki Tensai-tachi" kara no Monogatari
ANNÉE DE PRODUCTION  :  2017
STUDIOS  :  [NHK ENTERPRISE] [J.C. STAFF]
GENRES  :  [SPORT] [TRANCHE DE VIE]
AUTEURS  :  [ITOU TOMOYOSHI] [MORITA SHINGO]
TYPE & DURÉE  :   TV-S 25 mins (en cours)
==================
TITRE ORIGINAL  :  "Eiyuu" Kaitai
ANNÉE DE PRODUCTION  :  2016
STUDIO  :  [ZEXCS]
GENRE  :  [COMéDIE]
AUTEUR  :  [KOYAMA KYOUHEI]
TYPE & DURÉE  :  1 OAV
==================
TITRE ORIGINAL  :  "Parade" de Satie
ANNÉE DE PRODUCTION  :  2016
STUDIO  :  [YAMAMURA ANIMATION]
GENRES  :  [FANTASTIQUE & MYTHE] [COMéDIE] [MUSICAL]
AUTEUR  :  [SATIE ERIK]
TYPE & DURÉE  :  1 FILM 14 mins
==================
TITRE ORIGINAL  :  elDLIVE
ANNÉE DE PRODUCTION  :  2017
STUDIO  :  [PIERROT CO.,LTD.]
GENRES  :  [ACTION] [COMéDIE] [ESPACE & SCI-FICTION]
AUTEUR  :  [AMANO AKIRA]
TYPE & DURÉE  :  Non spécifié
==================
TITRE ORIGINAL  :  'n Gewone blou Maandagoggend
ANNÉE DE PRODUCTION  :  2014
STUDIO  :  [AUCUN]
GENRE  :  [DRAME]
AUTEUR  :  [KAMFER RONELDA]
TYPE & DURÉE  :  1 FILM 3 mins
```

Comment: i got "UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xc9' in position 3: ordinal not in range(128)" when i trying your code. However i search to get a dataframe  result with each of informations that you printed in purpose to export it in csv

Comment: Well, it is a typical encoding error, because the text contains none ASCII character. You can switch to use python3.X or using the utf-8 or unicode encoding. You can use python to transform the result from the program directly into csv and there will be a lot of solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Good choice on your libraries! I would also like to recommend using the urlpath library to simplify the requests a little.

```
pip install urlpath
```

Give this a try:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urlpath import URL
import pandas as pd

def scrape_page(url):
    res = url.get()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(res.content, "html.parser")
    anime_containers = soup.find_all('table', {'class':'animesindex'})
    anime_dictionary = {}
    for container in anime_containers:
        anime_name = container.find('td',{'class':'animestitle'}).a.text
        dic = {}
        for td in container.find_all('td', {'class':'animestxt'}):
            attr = [t.strip() for t in td.text.strip().split(':')]
            dic[attr[0]] = ':'.join(attr[1:])
            anime_dictionary[anime_name] = dic
    return anime_dictionary

url = URL('http://www.animeka.com/animes/~_{}.html'.format(1))
anime_dictionary = scrape_page(url)
df = pd.DataFrame(anime_dictionary)
print(df)
```

This code will work for a single page. The scrape_page function takes a urlpath object and uses it to make a request. I personally like the urlpath object as it interfaces nicely with pyhton's pathlib objects, urllib, and has requests built in. From there, we parse the page as a BeautifulSoup object. In the find_all method of the soup, I passed in a dictionary instead of using a keyword parameter as it will be more useful for passing multiple constraints when applying this code to future projects. Ultimately, the scrape_page function returns a dictionary of dictionaries as it is a very convenient structure for constructing a DataFrame and directly analogous to a DataFrame.

Modifying the code for multi-page use of this function would like the following:

```
anime_dictionary = {}
for i in range(466):
    url = URL('http://www.animeka.com/animes/~_{}.html'.format(i+1))
    anime_dictionary.update(scrape_page(url))
df = pd.DataFrame(anime_dictionary)
df.to_csv('file_name.csv')
```

The results after this point will exist inside a rather large pandas dataframe. The following shows an entry of the results:

```
                                       .hack//G.U. Trilogy  \
ANNÉE DE PRODUCTION                                    2008   
ANNÉES DE PRODUCTION                                    NaN   
AUTEUR                                                  NaN   
AUTEURS                [PROJECT .HACK] [SADAMOTO YOSHIYUKI]   
GENRE                                                   NaN   
GENRES                   [ACTION] [AVENTURE] [ANIMATION 3D]   
STUDIO                                                  NaN   
STUDIOS                [CYBERCONNECT2] [BANDAI NAMCO GAMES]   
TITRE ORIGINAL                          .hack//G.U. Trilogy   
TYPE & DURÉE                                 1 FILM 85 mins   
VOLUMES, TYPE & DURÉE                                   NaN
```

Going forward, it should not be too difficult to make the function more dynamic to be able to handle any webpage with a table of tables.